# Accessing context in a validator function of a static class

Tags: flutter, validation, textinput

There are various options to change a password through a localized app in a way like that:

```
MyTextFormField(
  controller: _passwordController,
  obscureText: true,
  labelText: S.of(context).label_newPassword,
  validatorFunction: Validators.validatePassword,
),
```

and there is a Validator class like that:

```
class Validators {
    static String validatePassword(String value) {
        if (value.isEmpty) {
          return S.of(MainApp.navKey.currentContext).hint_passwordMissing;
        } else if (value.length > 15 || value.length < 8) {
          return S.of(MainApp.navKey.currentContext).hint_wrongPasswordLength; 
        }
        return null;
      }
    }
```

That is working but is `MainApp.navKey.currentContext` the best way to access the context?

Comment: Why not passing the context as parameter to ```validatePassword```?

Answer (score 0):

Okay... works this way:

```
MyTextFormField(
  controller: _passwordController,
  obscureText: true,
  labelText: S.of(context).label_newPassword,
  validatorFunction: (s) => Validators.validatePassword(s, context),
),
```